# How to convert the iterated string values result set into arrays in ios?

Tags: ios, arrays

I wish to get the following result:

> set arr[0]=jan23,2016 …… upto arr[6] =jan29,2016.

For that I have the following code:

```
// To get future or next 6 days from now or current date
NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * datecomponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDayfromDate:[NSDate date]];
for(int i=0;i<6;++i)
{
    NSDate * todaydate = [calendar dateFromComponents:datecomponents];
    NSLog(@"%@",todaydate);
    ++datecomponents.day;
    NSDateFormatter * dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateformatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    NSString * convertedstring = [dateformatter stringFromDate:todaydate];
    NSLog(@“converteddate:%@",convertedstring);
```

For this I got a response like the following:

> converteddate:Jan 23, 2016 similarly upto jan29,2016

Then I do like this:

```
NSMutableString * newstring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[newstring stringByAppendingString:convertedstring];
NSLog(@"%@",newstring);
```

And also like this:

```
    NSMutableArray * arrdata;
    arrdata = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [arrdata addObject:convertedstring];
    NSLog(@"%@",arrdata);
}
```

How to get the above result set.after iteration of strings how to convert those into arrays.

Comment: @Fabio Berger how to do this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full answer:

```
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *datecomponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDayfromDate:[NSDate date]];

NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    NSDate * todaydate = [calendar dateFromComponents:datecomponents];
    NSLog(@"%@",todaydate);
    ++datecomponents.day;
    NSString *convertedstring = [dateformatter stringFromDate:todaydate];
    [arr addObject:convertedstring];
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can still optimize the code. It's not necessary at all to create a new date formatter in each iteration.

Comment: @vadian: Thanks for pointing this. I missed out while editing.
To catherine007: I made a little change in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The array must be declared and allocated outside of the `for` loop as you are resetting it every iteration:

```
NSMutableArray * arrdata = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];
NSDateComponents * datecomponents = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDayfromDate:[NSDate date]];
for(int i=0;i<6;++i)
```

Also there is no need to do this, as you never really use `newstring` anyway:

```
NSMutableString * newstring = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[newstring stringByAppendingString:convertedstring];
```